# Are there any disadvantages of using a separate thread pool instead of common pool?

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool

Are there any disadvantages of using custom thread pool instead of common thread pool?
Situation: Suppose i have one java application which is running on tomcat server (which having default 200 worker thread), if i create custom thread pool with 300 worker thread then this affect my application?

Comment: Well yea.  Creating a thread pool of that size is probably a mistake.   Generally speaking, "lots of threads" is a problem rather than a solution.  Why do you need that many threads?

Comment: i want to use custom thread pool to execute some business logic for performance, but i want to understand what problem i'll face when i'll use  custom thread pool

Comment: Performance problems ... unless you have lots of cores and RAM sitting idle!   Adding more threads doesn't make your computer more powerful.  (If it did, we could all make millions of bucks by mining bitcoins on little laptops with lots and lots of threads.)